# How can I dynamically populate the checkbox value?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I this on my markup page:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="sections" class="checkAll" />
```

It uses jQuery for checkall/uncheckall checkboxes thanks to @Raminson.

Then I have this on codefile:
Me.sections.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "Miracle Alley")

This works.

Issue I am having now is that we would like to populate the values of the checkbox dynamically from the database.

I am kind of stuck. Below is my attempt at doing so.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT section FROM myTable"
            Dim connStr As String = 
              ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr").ConnectionString
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            Dim objReader As SqlDataReader

            objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            '   |||||   Loop through the Reader to retrieve data    
            '   |||||   and set each checkbox to appropriate data from datasource
            While objReader.Read()
                With objReader
                    sections.Checked = .Item("section")
                End With
            End While
            Me.sessions.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "sections")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am sorry for choosing both c# and vb.net tags. Any help in any of the flavors would be greatly appreciated.

One of the issues is I keep getting this error:

***Input string was not in a correct format.*** 
 which is on this line:

sections.Checked = .Item("section")

I am just trying to assign the value of db field section to the checkbox value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The CheckBox control creates a check box on the Web Forms page that
>   allows the user to switch between a true or false state.

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s78d0k1(v=vs.71).aspx

I recommend using CheckBoxList instead of CheckBox.

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="sections" CssClass="checkAll" />
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="sect" CssClass="checkAll" >
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code Behind:

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT section FROM myTable"
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
        Dim objReader As SqlDataReader

        objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        '   |||||   Loop through the Reader to retrieve data    
        '   |||||   and set each checkbox to appropriate data from datasource
        While objReader.Read()
            With objReader
                Dim li As New ListItem(objReader(0).ToString())
                sect.Items.Add(li)
            End With
        End While

    End If
```

PS -

I get a warning with the inclusion of the class="checkAll" value pair.

> Message   1   Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'class' is not a valid attribute of element 'CheckBox'.

Use CssClass instead.

UPDATE (Adding Check/Uncheck All functionality)

Markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCheck" Text="Check All" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUncheck" Text="Uncheck All" OnClick="btnUncheck_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub btnCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    For Each listItem As ListItem In sect.Items
        listItem.Selected = True
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub btnUncheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUncheck.Click
    For Each listItem As ListItem In sect.Items
        listItem.Selected = False
    Next
End Sub
```

And don't forget these:

```
Protected WithEvents btnCheck As Button
Protected WithEvents btnUncheck As Button
```

Comment: Sorry good helpers. I got called into meeting.

@GrayFox374, your solution worked like a charm. Thank you very very much.


The code rendered the Checkall/uncheckall useless. I got to figure that out.

THANK YOU ALL!!

Answer (score 0):

Well I’m going to assume that the section column is of type bit? if so you can use the GetBoolean(0) method of the reader object,  I’m not too familiar with VB but the c# equivalent would be `sections.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("section"));`

Hope this helps

Comment: the fieldname is not a bit data type. Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated.

To me, this is one of the best technical forums.